# Best way to parse and display text similar to html in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What is the best way to parse texts similar to HTML and display them in a `UITableViewCell`?
The text is similar to HTML, but instead of `[tag]...[\tag]`, it uses `<tag>...<\tag>`, and some names of tags are different. 
Right now, what I think is to first replace tags using `String.replacingOccurrences`, then parse it to attributed text using

```
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString( data: ((str.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!)),
                    options: [.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                    documentAttributes: nil)
```

and then just display it with a `UITextView`.

But this approach seems to be slow. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You mean that it's a BBCode ?

Comment: ..Yeah, I think it is... I actually didn't know BBCode

Comment: Can you show a text example?

Comment: Is the webpage loading slow or is the actual conversion from HTML to string slow? How large is the webpage?

Comment: The webpage loading is okay. The conversion isn't very slow, it just seems to use the CPU heavily.